# Rewrite inpage javascript to js file

Tags: javascript, function

I use a piece of Javascript to display current weather on a dashboard. The function is writting in an "inpage" format, so in need the place it in my index.php. I want to move the function to my scripts.js, but how do I transform this code to work correctly? I am very new to Javascript functions... Any ideas?

```
           reallySimpleWeather.weather({
               wunderkey: '', // leave blank for Yahoo
               location: 'Holten, NL', //your location 
               woeid: '', // "Where on Earth ID"
               unit: 'c', // 'c' also works

               success: function(weather) {
                 html = '<div id="weergraden">'+weather.temp+'&#176;'+' graden</div>';
                 html += '<div id="weerstatus">'+weather.currently.replace("Mostly ", "Veelal ").replace("Showers" , "Regenbuien").replace("Sunny", "Zonnig").replace("Partly ", "Lichte ").replace("Cloudy", "Bewolking").replace("Rain", "Regen").replace("Scattered " , "Verspreide ").replace("Clear", "Helder")+'</div>';
              html += '<img src="'+weather.image+'"></img>';
              //html += "<img src='"+serverurl+"weer/"+weather.currently.replace(" ", "_")+".png'></img>";
              document.getElementById('weer').innerHTML = html; 
              setInterval(weather, 6000);
               },
               error: function(error) {
              document.getElementById('weer').innerHTML = '<p>'+error+'</p>';
               }
           });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just copypaste this code to separate file for example app.js, 
and than connect it to your php page.

```
<?php echo"<script language='javascript' src='reallySimpleWeatherCDN'></script>";?>
<?php echo"<script language='javascript' src=/javascript/app.js></script>";?>
```

Consider that you are connecting app.js after reallySimpleWeather library

Comment: was my answer helpful?